# Live Server Extension in VS Code is not working in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been working with visual studio a long of time ago in Windows without any problems.
I installed WSL in my PC, all perfect.

But now I migrated one of my webpages directory to the WSL root
\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\user\webPage

And when I click on "Live Server" extension, it loads propertly in:
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html

But when I make a change and save, is not working

Do I have to change something else? Of course all the extensions are installed, seems to be the same

[image: VS Image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but when trying it on Windows, it was working correctly, so I guess that Live Server will try to load it as localhost (which is 127...) but WSL doesn't use that. This can be confirmed by running ifconfig on the WSL Terminal.

I found a setting on the extension called "Use local IP". Once checked, it will open the Window with the WSL address instead of localhost and changes are shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this settings in your VS Code extension:

```
"liveServer.settings.https": {
    "passphrase": "true",
    "key": "true",
    "cert": "true",
    "enable": 1
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not tried this, but the way I answered was helfull too :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

1. Install [Remote Development extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) pack in VSCode and then close VSCode.
2. Install wslview using `$sudo apt install wslu`.
3. Open the folder containing your html file using `$code <folder_name>`.
4. Make sure that the bottom left corner is showing WSL:Ubuntu. If not, click on that button and choose new WSL window and choose your project folder in WSL directory.
5. You may be required to reinstall live server extension in the WSL VScode window. Once installed, add or update this line in the setting.json of live server extension `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "wslview"`. VSCode may flag "wslview" as a problem/error, just neglect it.
6. In your WSL terminal run the command `$BROWSER='wslview'`.

Now check if the live server is working properly or not.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install this extension [Remote Developer Extenson Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)

Once you do this, open your Visual Studio normally and you will be able to develop, there are some extensions not compatible.

More references [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)

It is important to see in your VS code in the left-down side, that you are in WSL:Ubuntu in color green, You can also open in that side[WSL UBUNTU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDALA.png)